# If $Y=X_1+X_2$, does talking about joint distribution of $(Y,X_1,X_2)$ make sense?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am unsure because $Y$ results from$X_1$ and $X_2$, so perhaps all the information contained in $(Y,X_1,X_2$ would be contained in $(X_1,X_2)$?

Also, if talking about $(Y,X_1,X_2)$ does make sense, then this joint distribution would put $0$ density on any $Y\not = X_1+X_2$ yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint distribution does make sense, but it does not have a density: it is concentrated on the plane $y = x_1 + x_2$.

Comment: This goes beyond my original question, but It does not have a density? I am assuming this is because the plane does not have any volume, but couldn't we still assign a probability to each $(x_1,x_2)$ pair in the plane, and wouldn't doing that give rise to a density function (stated differently: doesn't a density function say, for every pair, what the probability of that pair occurring is -- or the probably of being in an interval containing the pair --, and can't we do that here?)

Comment: No, the values of a density function are not probabilities.  The probability of each $(x_1, x_2)$ pair is $0$.  Densities are functions that you integrate to get probabilities.  In this case we're talking about a density with respect to ($3$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure.  If the distribution is not absolutely continuous with respect to that measure, i.e. there is a set of measure $0$ whose probability is not $0$, then the distribution does not have a density.